# Is there a way to send/receive Tcp messages without sustaining a connection and without reopening a connection each time?

Tags: tcp, message-queue, mq

I want to implement a basic message queue server. The server will be able to receive messages (byte arrays) and store them, and send messages to requesting clients.

I want to decide which protocol to base my custom protocol over.

Tcp seems natural for this kind of thing. But it seems that with Tcp, each time a client wants to send a message to the MQ server it has to establish a connection. It can't just 'send away' the message. Or, I can sustain a message between the client and MQ server, but I'm not sure that's a good idea.

So is there a way in Tcp to simply 'send a message' without establishing a connection each time? If not, what protocol should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way in Tcp to simply 'send a message' without establishing a connection each time?

No.

> If not, what protocol should I use for this?

UDP is a connectionless protocol, but it also lacks guaranteed sequencing and retransmission. You would have to build an ACK-based or NACK-based protocol over it.

What's your objection to TCP connections?